# Android - Zxing to Scan and Create new QR Code Image

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code

I have seen different versions of `Zxing` library for different languages and platforms but still could find a perfect one that suits my needs. I want to create a QR Code from a `String` and also Scan a QRCode image to retrieve data from it text. For the scanning part, I think forcing user to install another app is not a good idea. So I don't want to use the `Zxing-Android-Integration` Library. I have also checked [Zbar](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), but it doesn't help creating QR Code images. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create the QR Code in android as well? I use zint to create QR codes in windows, and ZXing to scan them in Android

Comment: Also, you can take the source from the ZXing library so the user doesn't actually have to download it from the play store.  If you don't mind using network in your app, the google charts api provides a really simple mechanism to create a QR code

Comment: I tried including the ZXing core and the Zxing android app source in my project. But now when I try to run the application, I am getting this error `Error:(59, 36) error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)` at different parts of the Zxing's source. I think its not supported in 1.6, but I have 1.7 installed `java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
` . What do I do now?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change compiler options.  If you're using eclipse w/ android sdk then go to project-> properties-> java compiler and change the compiler compliance level to 1.7

Comment: I am on android studio. And I checked that it is using Java 1.7, which is the only JDK on my machine.

Comment: Ok. Got rid of the errors that were mostly caused due to non support of 1.7 features by replacing those syntaxes, with the help of Android Studio. And few little tweaks here and there.